# C#-The variable name '@startdate' has already been declared.Variable names must be unique a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a way to update a cell in my datagridview and save it to database using queries but I’m getting this exception:

> The variable name '@startdate' has already been declared.Variable
>   names must be unique a query batch or stored procedure

Here is my code:

```
private void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query2 = "UPDATE [Semester] SET [Start_Date]=@startdate, " +
                        " [End_Date]=@enddate WHERE [Sem_Num]=@sem";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", 
                                       dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", 
                                       dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem", 
                                  Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: And in particular in this context where dates are converted to strings and the database need to reconvert those strings back to dates. A recipe for bugs.

Comment: You should not keep a global conn object. Just create a new one inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the parameters in each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem", Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
    this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Or define parameters outside the loop and set the value inside of it:

```
var startParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
var endParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
var semParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sem", SqlDbType.Int);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    startParam.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    endParam.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    semParam.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding new parameters to the same command every time you run through the loop.

You need to either clear the parameters or make a new command.